# What should I do about a long delay for nominating referees for my PhD dissertation?

Tags: phd, thesis, thesis-committee

I have submitted my dissertation for a PhD degree some 6 months ago to my department but my advisor has yet to complete the examiner-nomination procedure.  For this delay in completing the procedure he is claiming that he has a "lot of work" and will "do it soon".

Is this normal?  What should I do about it?

Comment: What have you been doing for six months? Are you funded? What are your plans/options for this current academic year?

Comment: additional context would be helpful (what country for instance)

Comment: Yes, additional context would be very valuable. I’m having a hard time figuring out your situation because in my own experience, the readers of my dissertation were the people who sat for my (oral) defense, and it fell on me, the student, to line them up ahead of time.

Answer (score 2):

This is extremely abnormal and it reflects poorly on your supervisor and your Department.  Depending on the rules at your university, it might also be a breach of the administrative rules and timeframes set for higher degrees.  Typically, a primary supervisor should be working on identifying and contacting appropriate referees for a PhD dissertation *prior to its submission* and should submit the formal examiner-nomination paperwork during the "notification of intent to submit" phase, which happens before submission of the dissertation.  This gives the referees some advanced warning that the dissertation is coming.  It would then be typical to send the dissertation to the referees shortly after submission and to expect the referees to complete their review of the dissertation within 2-3 months of receipt.  The entire process should usually take less than six-months from submission, though it is sometimes pushed out when there is a non-responsive referee or an alternate referee needs to be used.  It is unlikely that there is any valid reason for a six-month delay after submission, and "a lot of work" is certainly not a valid reason.

At this point, the first things you should do is to read the higher-degree rules and submission/examination rules for your PhD degree to see the university process and timeframes for the refereeing phase.  (Since I don't know what university you're in I can't find these for you, but here is [an example](https://policies.anu.edu.au/ppl/document/ANUP_012815) of these kinds of rules from my own institution.  As you can see, they typically specify the procedure for when relevant forms are submitted, etc.)  Once you have done that, I recommend you go outside your own Department and speak to the relevant Dean of Higher Degrees/Research (or whatever is the equivalent staff member in your university).  This person can take action if your supervisor is behind the expected university timeframes (which is almost certainly the case).

It reflects poorly on your Department that they are not able to complete administrative tasks of this kind within reasonable times.  This causes delay in refereeing and completion for their PhD candidates, which can have follow-on effects to employment.  At minimum, your Department needs a kick up the arse by a relevant senior administrator in the university.  It is likely that your supervisor will also require re-training in relation to expectations for administering a PhD candidature.